# How to give initial value for DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and fix error Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I want to delete checked rows in DatagGidView from the database , I searched the available questions in this site but i cannot find the exact answer how to avoid null value error if checkbox not checked for the row.

I created DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, and I need to delete selected (checked) rows from database when click delete button.

[image: DGV]

I tried the following code:

First I created the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn  when get data from the database

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxdelete = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dgvprice.Columns.Add(checkboxdelete);
checkboxdelete.HeaderText = "Select";
checkboxdelete.Name = "delete";
dgvprice.DataSource = pricelist.GET_CUSTOMER_PRICELIST(Convert.ToInt32(textCustId.Text));
```

Then the code for delete button I tried more than one solution checking null value but also not working :

```
private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvprice.Rows)
    {
        // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))

        bool status = (bool)dgvprice.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
        if (status)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mamlakalabConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Customers_Price_List where testid = '" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "' and custid = '" + textCustId.Text + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully", "Successfull operation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

I tried the following questions also but no exact solution for my case:

- [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- [How to know a specific checkbox inside datagridview is checked or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439758/how-to-know-a-specific-checkbox-inside-datagridview-is-checked-or-not)
- [How to get datagridviewcheckboxcolumn value c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742565/how-to-get-datagridviewcheckboxcolumn-value-c)
- [Delete multiple rows in a DataGridView(table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107369/delete-multiple-rows-in-a-datagridviewtable)

I need the exact answer please I am new to .NET 
what to do to fix this error?

Comment: @JQSOFT when i create the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn  after setting the datasource of datagridview the column will appear last column , but i need it to appear first column.

Comment: `dgvprice.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxdelete);`

Comment: I added this codedgvprice.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxdelete);  but give me error

Comment: What error now?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Provided column already belongs to the DataGridView control.

Comment: the error before load data to grid view

Comment: Remove the `dgvprice.Columns.Add(checkboxdelete);` and use `dgvprice.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxdelete);` instead.

Comment: still same error when click delete button  Object reference not set to an instance of an object on this line bool status = (bool)dgvprice.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;

Comment: Change this `bool status = (bool)dgvprice.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;` with `bool status = (bool)row.Cells[0].Value;` Also, you need to reconsider the `delete` routine.

Comment: same error with this code bool status = (bool)row.Cells[0].Value;  actually i tried more than one solution but give same error with this code also if (bool.Parse(datarow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())) , i found these solutions in youtube , can you advice me if you have another way thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: OK, try this instead: `var status = (bool)row.Cells[0].FormattedValue;`

Comment: @JQSOFT Thank you sooooo much thats is the point its working 100% , I will search now what is the different between .Value and .Formattedvalue :) . please answer the question and i will accept as correct answer .

Comment: No problem mate next time :). btw, Don't forget to reconsider the `delete` routine. Use the same connection object, use parameters instead of string concat and dispose the disposable objects when you finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mr JQSOFT for your answer , 
I changed the following :

```
dgvprice.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxdelete);
```

instead of

```
dgvprice.Columns.Add(checkboxdelete);
```

then the delete button changed

```
bool status = (bool)row.Cells[0].FormattedValue;
```

instead of

```
bool status = (bool)dgvprice.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```